# Magento 2 Cart Slider Not Showing any products

Tags: php, magento, magento2, shopping-cart

I am facing this problem on one of my magento Sites. This error is showing up in Console and cart items are not showing up.

> Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "foreach: function
>   (){return
>   $parent.getRegion($parent.getItemRenderer(item.product_type)) }"
>   Message: Cannot read property 'simple' of undefined    at
>   UiClass.getItemRenderer (minicart.js:127)    at foreach (eval at
>   createBindingsStringEvaluator (knockout.js:2624), :3:93)
>   at knockout.js:3889    at Object.init (knockout.js:5023)    at init
>   (knockout.js:3914)    at knockout.js:2989    at Object.ignore
>   (knockout.js:1249)    at knockout.js:2988    at Object.arrayForEach
>   (knockout.js:151)    at applyBindingsToNodeInternal (knockout.js:2974)